# Версия для печати HTML страницы

Tags: css, html5, print

Использую bootstrap. Настроил адаптивку, но при выводе страницы на печать слетает вся верстка.

Слышал, что для печати делается отдельно верстка. Можно ли как-то упустить этот момент и никак не изменять стили и расположение блоков, чтобы напечатать страницу, как она есть?

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принята практика: **один** вопрос — один (и более) ответов на него. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. задать другой вопрос — с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе Вы правильно все слышали - нужна отдельная верстка.
Для печати надо создавать отдельные `media` запросы.

```
@media print {
    /* [ваши стили] */
}
```

Может быть имеет смысл запихнуть даже в отдельный `.css` файл, для удобства.

Насчет второго вопроса - как Вам сказали в комментах, оформите его как отдельный вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не выходит, в основных стилях пробую 
@media print{
html,body{
background-color:black !important;
}
}
но при предварительном просмотре никаких изменений...

Comment: "importnant" у вас неправильно написано. Может быть в этом проблема? Также попробуйте на цвет фона менять, а что-то другое. Все-таки не все принтеры/браузеры/системы любят это на печати. Попробуйте поменять фон или сделать рамку о какого-нибудь элемента... Ну просто чтобу убелиться, что `@media print {}` читается

Comment: в коде important правильно было написано, Вы оказались правы, видимо недопустимо для print background color всего документа.

Comment: Если я ответил на Ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, пометьте ответ как принятый (галочка слева от ответа). надо повышать статистику отвеченных вопросов. :) Спасибо

Comment: И не забудьте удалить второй вопрос из этого вопрос и оформить его отдельно.